# opencv convertScaleAbs in Sobel

Tags: c++, opencv, sobel

**I do the Sobel calculation in OPENCV3.1.0. I can't understand why it should do 'convertScaleAbs' here.**

The following is the main code:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace cv;
int main( int, char** argv )
{
  Mat src, src_gray;
  Mat grad;
  const char* window_name = "Sobel Demo - Simple Edge Detector";
  int scale = 1;
  int delta = 0;
  int ddepth = CV_16S;
  src = imread( argv[1] );
  if( src.empty() )
    { return -1; }
  GaussianBlur( src, src, Size(3,3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY );
  namedWindow( window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  Mat grad_x, grad_y;
  Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;
  //Scharr( src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  Sobel( src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );
  //Scharr( src_gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  Sobel( src_gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );
  addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad );
  imshow( window_name, grad );
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Who can help explain it? Thank you!

Comment: because this code doesn't compute the real magnitude but only an approximation. Sobel gradients are signed, that's why you need the absolute value if you want to approximate the magnitude by a simple weighted sum.

Comment: It's computing (half of) L1 gradient: "abs(x) + abs(y)", instead of L2: "sqrt(x^2 + y^2)"